# Data Truncation exceptions and Spring MVC

Tags: java, database, spring, spring-mvc, architecture

**Context**

I have a 3 layer architecture web application based on Spring Framework:

*DAO<--Service<--Web application*

The current DAO implementation uses Springs *jdbcTemplate*. The web application is built with *Spring MVC*.

**Question**

Which technique is appropiate to stop data truncation exceptions coming from the DAO layer? Is it correct to cut the inputs in the service layer? Should we  rely on validators in the controllers or services? Should we just throw exceptions in the service layer?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using spring , then you create a class that implements validator. [Here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html) is something that will help you out.